# How to clean almost periodic noise?

Tags: python, matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I have signal that looks like this:
[image]

As you can see there are some almost periodic pulses at the background with amplitude about 1000. I am saying almost, because, if you zoom in,  you may see that they slightly differ from each other, plus there may be intervals without them, something like between 35000 and 40000.

How can I get rid of these pulses?

[csv with data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByATqxQWgjs9dEpMTXdzR1F1RnM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You could use a notch filter to remove that frequency, or even just a low pass if it is higher than your frequency of interest. You will introduce a time delay though ....

Comment: This might be a better place to ask http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you know the sampling frequency that this was obtained at?